# How to set custom RadzenDropDown item to be shown on page load?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, blazor, dropdown, radzen

I have populated a RadzenDropDown in the code shown below,

```
<RadzenDropDown @bind-Value="SomethingValueSelected" TValue="int" AllowFiltering="false" AllowClear="false" SelectedItem="0" SelectedItemsText="Test-1"
                        Data=@SomethingList TextProperty="Name" ValueProperty="Value"/>
```

Here is the list with populated items:

```
List<SomethingDTO> SomethingList= new List<SomethingDTO>(){ new SomethingDTO{ Name = "Test-1", Value = -1 },
                                                                                new SomethingDTO{ Name = "Test0", Value = 0 },
                                                                                new SomethingDTO{ Name = "Test1", Value = 1 },
                                                                                new SomethingDTO{ Name = "Test2", Value  = 2 },
                                                                                new SomethingDTO{ Name = "Test5", Value = 5 }};
int SomethingValueSelected;
```

And here is what i get when page loads:
[image][image]

**My question is**, how do I get automatically selected item called "Test-1", with the value of -1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it seems like quite a simple one -
just set the value of element that is being binded to a value that you prefer, in my case it was

```
int SomethingValueSelected = -1;
```